# GAE simple app question

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am learning GAE with python. I am trying to build the simplest possible application: get name from user; write name to datastore; retrieve name and display page. I tried the tutorial but I still do not understand how to do this. I appreciate any answers. Thank you

Comment: 1) Post your code, only the relevant parts 2) Post your output / error messages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i´m going to post a little snippet:
Create a file in your root directory, name it main.py

```
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

# Pagina principal
class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        if users.get_current_user():
            url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
            url_linktext = "Bem Vindo: "+ str(users.get_current_user()) + ".  Logout "
        else:
            url = users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)
            url_linktext = ' Entrar '
        values = {
                  'url': url,
                  'url_linktext': url_linktext,
                  }
        self.response.out.write(template.render('templates/index.html', values))

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
                                      ('/', MainPage),                                      
                                      ],debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

then create a folder in your root directory, name it templates. Inside templates create a file and name it base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="mainContainer">
      <!--menu-->
      <div id="menu">
        <ul id="menuUl">
          <li class="selected"><a href="/"> Inicio </a> </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Else</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--End menu-->

    </div>
     <hr />
    <!--End Navigation-->
    <div id="header" >

{% block header %} {% endblock %}

    </div>
    <div id="contentContainer">
      <!--content-->
      <div id="content">

{% block main %} {% endblock %}


      </div>

      <div id="contentBottom" >
        <div id="contentBottomLeft"></div>
        <div id="contentBottomRight"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      <div id="footerMenu">
        <ul>
          <li class="selected"><a href="/"> Inicio </a> </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ipca</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <p>Copyright &copy; 2010 Martin . Todos os direitos reservados.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

This page is static. This code **{% block main %} {% endblock %}** and this **{% block header %} {% endblock %}** This code represents a variable that will receive a template. So if you want to put content on the header and content, you must create a new file, let's call index.html.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block header %}
    <div class="hello">
       <a href="{{ url }}">{{ url_linktext }}</a>    
    </div>

{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
        <h1>Um pouco de palha</h1>
        <p class="smallSubtitle">Isto e mais palha .......</p>

{% endblock %}
```

When you create a new template file, you have to put this code **{% extends "base.html" %}** and then you´ll call the block from header and content and fill it up.

What this does is present a page with Login info in it´s header. If you haven´t login yet it redirects you to login, else (it means, you´ve already login) shows the Logout button. Then presents dummy content on content block